# XPath performance -which one is better?

Tags: performance, xpath

I have a question concerning performance issues when using XPath.

Which one is better and why? (in case of performance of course):

```
//A/B/C[@id="x"]/../..
```

vs.

```
//A[B/C[@id="x"]]
```

Comment: Why don't you try both and see which one is best in your environment, (which you did not tell us much about)  and with your data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anything, you'll get hit on performance by using `//` ... it is likely that the processor is not going to optimize such an expression and will waste time looking for `A` elements as a descendent of `C` elements because you are asking it to.  I highlight this in the classroom as one of the most common sources of poor performance in XSLT processing (and I cringe every time I see it being abused in StackOverflow questions, but I would spend all day talking about it because it is used so often).

As for the difference between `A/B/C[@id='x']/../..` and `A[B/C[@id="x"]]`, it depends if the processor rewrites the former into the latter as part of optimization (since it is declarative).

If no such optimization happens, the former will be slower than the latter because the former is asking the processor to take the time to collect all `C` elements and walk backup up the tree unioning the grandparent element of each one.  Whereas the latter expression uses a predicate that is a boolean true()/false() test of a data-type that is a node set, and the processor knows that the boolean value returned is true() at the first detection of such a `C` element and doesn't need to look for any other `C` elements (and shouldn't be looking for any other `C` elements).

Comment: thank you for an answer. could you be more specific about how exactly the second expression is evaluated? I did not quite get this. Where exactly this predicates true()/false() are used? On `A` elements?

Comment: By definition a predicate is an "effective boolean value" expression that is evaluated with a true()/false() result and if the result is false() the item is discarded from the addressed list.  If the result is true() the item is maintained in the addressed list.  The data-type of the predicate `B/C[@id='x']` is a node set.  The effective boolean value of a node set is false() for an empty node set and true() for a non-empty node set.  When the processor determines with the first item that the node set is not empty, there is no need to look for any more to know the value is true().

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, because in a second query we use predicate ``B/C[@id="x"]`` the processor have proper node set somewhere/somehow prepared and there is not need to collect all ``C`` elements and walk backup the tree unioning as in first query?

Comment: Correct, though it doesn't need to actual prepare a node set.  As soon as the processor finds one C with the attribute, it has no need to keep looking for another ... it can stop and accept the element A as having been qualified by the predicate.  Whether it does continue or not is up to the processor, but a well-written processor won't continue looking.  And whether it creates a node set or not is up to the processor, but a well-written processor will not and will simply note that the node set would be non-empty without having to actually take the overhead to prepare one.